# Git GUI not loading on iMac

Tags: macos, git, user-interface, git-gui

I've just bought a new iMac and I've hooked my Git repo up to it but I'm receiving the following error when launching Git GUI:

git-gui died of signal 11

Can anyone suggest a solution for me?

My Git version is: 1.7.12.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem : My solution: install 1.7.11.3 instead